# Copy cell values and cell comments when another cell contains certain values

Tags: vba, excel

I had previously received great assistance with this code. 
It copies the formulas from column A to column D and the values from column B to column E if the cells in column C contains a list of values (Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4).

I now need to also copy across the cell comments as well as cell values from column B to column E.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

```
Sub RangeCopyPaste()

Dim cell As Range

Range("D6:E1000").Clear

Set OcRange = Range("D6") 'Set the first destination cell

For Each cell In Worksheets("OverviewTest").Range("C6:C1000") 'Loop through your Status column
    Select Case cell.Value 'Select Case is an alternative to writing multiple If, ElseIf statements, particularly if you want it to run the same code when it is true.
        Case "Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4" 'Specify all the values which would consitute a "True" result
            OcRange.Formula = Range(cell.Offset(0, -2), cell.Offset(0, -2)).Formula 'Copies the formula from Column A
            OcRange.Offset(0, 1).Value = Range(cell.Offset(0, -1), cell.Offset(0, -1)).Value ' Copies the value from Column B
            Set OcRange = OcRange.Offset(1, 0) 'Setup the new destination cell ready for the next "True" result
    End Select
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: You have to show some effort on your part. Have you looked online? What have you found/ tried?

Comment: Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513)

Comment: you already have code to copy values from B to E .... just add the code to copy comments .... you have to figure it out yourself

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your feedback. I am new to VBA but looked at a lot of pages from: stackoverflow.com, msdn.microsoft.com, mrexcel.com, excelforum.com, excel.tips.net, ozgrid.com, experts-exchange.com

Most of the approaches involved using 'Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteComments' or 'Range.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteComments' but when I tried to incorporate this into the existing code, it did not work.

Thanks for your feedback, in future I will add in what I have tried previously to help rule these out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
OcRange.Formula = Range(cell.Offset(0, -2), cell.Offset(0, -2)).Formula
OcRange.Offset(0, 1).Value = Range(cell.Offset(0, -1), cell.Offset(0, -1)).Value
```

With this:

```
Range(cell.Offset(0, -2), cell.Offset(0, -2)).Copy
OcRange.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormulas)
OcRange.PasteSpecial (xlPasteComments)

Range(cell.Offset(0, -1), cell.Offset(0, -1)).Copy
OcRange.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
OcRange.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteComments)
```

That should do the trick.